# fpdf : increase size of footer and add multiple lines in pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am using FPDF to generate a report.

I have a fairly large amount of data I want to put in my footer. i.e the name and signatures of three people

I would like it to be on multiple lines.

PROBLEM: It keeps on being pushed out of focus. Not to the next page buti cannot see it once it reaches near the botton of the page.

Also, if shown, it is shown once at the end of the page only...

How do I increase the size of the footer?

this is the code for my footer

```
 function Footer() {
    $date=date(' jS  F Y ');
    $this->Cell(-28,150,$date,10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-190,150,$date,10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-50,150,$date,10,0,'C');

    $this->Cell(75,130,'The Village Market Representative',10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(195,130,'Betting Control and licensing Board Representative',10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-55,130,'Witness',10,0,'C');
 }
```

How would I do this so as to have it on every page and not have my footer pushed out of focus?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setY() to set cursor location above the bottom of the page before writing out your cells:

```
function Footer() {
    $this->setY(-30); 
    $date=date(' jS  F Y ');
    $this->Cell(-28,150,$date,10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-190,150,$date,10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-50,150,$date,10,0,'C');

    $this->Cell(75,130,'The Village Market Representative',10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(195,130,'Betting Control and licensing Board Representative',10,0,'C');
    $this->Cell(-55,130,'Witness',10,0,'C');
 }
```

Most examples I see online utilizing setY() to set footer use (-15), but that seemed to always push the footer onto the next page for me, so I set the negative value higher. The negative value sets the Y position based off of the bottom of the page.